# Ubuntu 20.04 is freezing every login, what can I do to diagnose?

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, encryption, freeze

The hardware all passes the dell diagnostics and the SMART check on the hard disk.

The laptop is freezing randomly, sometimes at the disk decryption screen, sometimes after 10 minutes of logging in, sometimes at the login screen.

The most bizarre symptom is as follows:
If i log in normally, it barely gets past the decryption screen, if it does, it freezes in the first two minutes, like fully freezes. ctrl+alt+f2 does nothing.

However, However, it seems like if I do the recovery mode, then choose "boot as normal" it works just fine indefinitely.

This is my lsw:

```
kins-latitude-7490
    description: Notebook
    product: Latitude 7490 (081C)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: D881SN2
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.1.0 dmi-3.1.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Latitude sku=081C uuid=44454C4C-3800-1038-8031-C4C04F534E32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0KP0FT
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: /D881SN2/CNCMK008550553/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.18.0
          date: 01/07/2021
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 4d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
             product: CT8G4SFS824A.M8FE
             vendor: 859B0000802C
             physical id: 0
             serial: E2D0C28C
             slot: DIMM A
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
             product: CT8G4SFS824A.M8FE
             vendor: 859B0000802C
             physical id: 1
             serial: E2D0C278
             slot: DIMM B
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 51
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 52
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 53
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 54
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3058MHz
          capacity: 3600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 08
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: UHD Graphics 620
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 08
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:ec240000-ec247fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:ec230000-ec23ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.11.0-36-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.11
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Video
                   product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
                   vendor: CNFGH19O1344000272E2
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 68.25
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.10
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: 5880
                   vendor: Broadcom Corp
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@1:a
                   version: 1.01
                   serial: 0123456789ABCD
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.11.0-36-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.11
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:1
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:ec25a000-ec25afff
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:ec259000-ec259fff
        *-generic:3
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:ec258000-ec258fff
        *-generic:4
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:ec257000-ec257fff
        *-generic:5
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:19 memory:ec256000-ec256fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:129 memory:ec255000-ec255fff
        *-raid
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: raid msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:125 memory:ec250000-ec251fff memory:ec254000-ec2540ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:ec253000-ec2537ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 memory:ec100000-ec1fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:126 memory:ec100000-ec100fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:ec000000-ec0fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 78
                serial: 5c:5f:67:c7:67:2b
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-36-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.50.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:130 memory:ec000000-ec001fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:d4000000-ea0fffff ioport:b0000000(size=570425344)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:ec24c000-ec24ffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:131 memory:ec248000-ec24bfff memory:ec220000-ec22ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:ec252000-ec2520ff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             logical name: enp0s31f6
             version: 21
             serial: 10:65:30:48:04:8f
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-36-generic firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:128 memory:ec200000-ec21ffff
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi
          physical id: 9
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SK hynix SC311 S
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 0P10
             serial: EJ84N509611104B1N
             size: 238GiB (256GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=b4709f27-7dea-47b7-8cba-789f23ce4908 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: cad8-2d61
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /boot
                version: 1.0
                serial: 5b75ef55-6c6c-4ed1-87d0-f995cff05bc7
                size: 732MiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2021-03-25 20:37:30 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2021-09-22 16:45:43 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2021-09-22 16:45:43 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: EFI partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: 969c0072-9032-4f9b-9ce9-9a136a18aa2c
                size: 237GiB
                capacity: 237GiB
                width: 237136840 bits
                capabilities: encrypted luks initialized
                configuration: bits=4532104136 filesystem=luks hash=sha256 version=2
  *-battery
       product: DELL DM3WC64
       vendor: SMP
       physical id: 1
       version: 04/11/2018
       serial: 134C
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 60000mWh
       configuration: voltage=7.6V
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth6246db8
       serial: 5a:16:79:83:31:d9
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```